# Argparser returns "--mode=client --port=52085" and crashes

Tags: python, argparse

Whenever I use `parser.parse_args()`, the kernel crashes. For instance:

```py
import argparse
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--return_counts", type=bool, default=True)

opt = parser.parse_args()

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
```

It gives this error:

> usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [--return_counts RETURN_COUNTS] 
>   pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --port=52085

But, if I use `parser.parse_known_args()`, it works.

```py
import argparse
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--return_counts", type=bool, default=True)

opt, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
```

It works, and `opt` gives this:

```py
print(opt)
Out[3]: Namespace(return_counts=True)
```

And `unknown` gives this:

```py
Out[4]: ['--mode=client', '--port=52162']
```

Can someone explain the sorcery behind this?

Comment: By the way, I get your unintended extra arguments, mode & port, iif I execute my script in PyCharm (Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you aren't providing the correct arguments to your command line. You need to add more arguments to the parser.

```
import argparse
import numpy as np

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--return_counts", type=bool, default=True)
parser.add_argument("--mode", default='client')
parser.add_argument("--port", default=52162)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now you can use `python3 pydevconsole.py --return_counts True --mode client --port 52162` in the command line and you will see:

```
print(args.return_counts) # True
print(args.mode) # client
print(args.port) # 52162
```

Comment: I am also getting the same error as unrecognized arguments model and port, when I run this from Pycharm's Python Console, but runs fine in other consoles.

Answer (score 4):

`parse_args` and `parse_known_args` use `sys.argv` unless you pass an argument to them (for instance `parser.parse_args(['a', 'b', 'c'])`)

whatever thing you started (presumably ipython / jupyter / etc.) was started with `--mode=client --port=52162`

The reason `parse_known_args` doesn't produce an error and exit is because it *only parses the known* arguments -- and not producing an error for unknown arguments (it can still produce errors for known arguments, for instance if they're the wrong type)