# I get a pydevconsole error when trying to get ezgmail to work. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am trying to initialise ezgmail but it gets stuck at the point of looking for a token.json file. It gives a warning first, that it cannot find the token.json file and then an error as follows and hangs up. The process I followed (I'm working in a venv in PyCharm) is as follows:

Process followed: 
Logged into google and enabled Gmail API; renamed it TestEmails;
Configure your Oauth client: I chose "Desktop App"
Copied resulting credentials.json file into the project folder

I even copied the quickstart.py file into my working directory and run it (python quickstart.py) without any problem. 
then:
(at Python Console: ) ::

```
>>>import os
>>>
```

The error I get is shown below:

```
import ezgmail
usage: pydevconsole.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                       [--noauth_local_webserver]
                       [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                       [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --port=60056

Process finished with exit code 2
```

Any insights would be much appreciated, happy to add further info if helpful. Cheers (I'm a novice, please treat gently!).

Comment: Already "import ezgmail" yields this error message in my case.

Answer (score 0):

apparently [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081228/argparser-returns-mode-client-port-52085-and-crashes) helped me to progress a bit further (still stuck, but further down the line!) . . . which meant I had to modify one of the packages I pip-installed. (oauth2client.tools). So I'll close this unless anyone else has any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to answer without without the actual code you are trying to debug. But here are some suggestions. try using absolute paths instead of relative paths if you already have configured and downloaded your access token for the Gmail API.

if you are having trouble generating a token, maybe try to run the python code from command line so it will use your default browser to take you to the authorization screen. I have had trouble getting jupyter notebook to use my browser to open authorization screens.

the following code is from quickstart.py and it should show you how token.json is first generated:

```
def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
Lists the user's Gmail labels.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
```

Answer (score 0):

rename your credentials-json file to credentials-gmail.json if not so already (you should have this in your root)